# Vba excel extract text from string between given length

Tags: vba, excel

Vba excel :
From a string stored in cells(2,1) with 255 characters I am trying to copy the first 50 characters into one cell and then 50 to 100 into other, 150 to 200 to other

I have a string stored in cells(2,1) with 255 characters and want to extarct 50 words, I mean bifiricated into 5 cells with each 50 sequence characters. I have used below code but the characters are not copy for given limit it continues with earlier earlier limit. Can you please help

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 1) = Data_comp 
Comp_data1 = Left(Data_comp, 50) ' copying 50 characters
Comp_data2 = Mid(Data_comp, 50, 100) ' copying 100 characters 
Comp_data3 = Mid(Data_comp, 100, 150) ' copying 150 characters 
Comp_data4 = Mid(Data_comp, 150, 200)' copying 200 characters 
Comp_data5 = Mid(Data_comp, 200, 250) ' copying 250 characters ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Manual_Checks").Cells(1, 2) = Comp_data1 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Manual_Checks").Cells(1, 3) = Comp_data2 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Manual_Checks").Cells(1, 4) = Comp_data3 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Manual_Checks").Cells(1, 5) = Comp_data4 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Manual_Checks").Cells(1, 6) = Comp_data5  
        abc1 = Len(Comp_data1) 'shows 50 characters 
        abc2 = Len(Comp_data2) ' shows 100 characters
         abc3 = Len(Comp_data3) '150 characters 
        abc4 = Len(Comp_data4) '200 characters
         abc5 = Len(Comp_data50 '250 characters
```

---

Comment: The third criteria in Mid() length not end so change the third criteria to 50 in all of them so `Mid(Data_comp, 200, 250)` should be `Mid(Data_comp, 200, 50)`

Answer (score 1):

You did it almost, but only a small correction is needed
**Mid Function (string, start, length)**
`Comp_data2 = Mid(Data_comp, 50, 100)` ==> `Comp_data2 = Mid(Data_comp, 51, 50)` 
`Comp_data3 = Mid(Data_comp, 100, 150)` ==> `Comp_data3 = Mid(Data_comp, 101, 50)` 
`Comp_data4 = Mid(Data_comp, 150, 200)` ==> `Comp_data4 = Mid(Data_comp, 151, 50)` 
`Comp_data5 = Mid(Data_comp, 200, 250)` ==> `Comp_data5 = Mid(Data_comp, 201, 50)`

Overall updated code is as follows

```
Dim Data_comp As String
Data_comp = "Some Text"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(9, 2) = Data_comp
Comp_data1 = Left(Data_comp, 50) 
Comp_data2 = Mid(Data_comp, 51, 50) 
Comp_data3 = Mid(Data_comp, 101, 50) 
Comp_data4 = Mid(Data_comp, 151, 50) 
Comp_data5 = Mid(Data_comp, 201, 50) 
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Manual_Checks").Cells(1, 2) = Comp_data1
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Manual_Checks").Cells(1, 3) = Comp_data2
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Manual_Checks").Cells(1, 4) = Comp_data3
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Manual_Checks").Cells(1, 5) = Comp_data4
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Manual_Checks").Cells(1, 6) = Comp_data5
        abc1 = Len(Comp_data1) 
        abc2 = Len(Comp_data2) 
         abc3 = Len(Comp_data3) 
        abc4 = Len(Comp_data4) 
         abc5 = Len(Comp_data50
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me tidy up and simplify the answer for **Raju** who has a good idea to start with. I am going to remove the Dim for Data_comp because it is not shown in the question.

```
Dim arrData(4) as String, abc(4) as Integer
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 1) = Data_comp
For intI = 0 to 4
    arrData(intI) = Mid(Data_comp, iniI * 50 + 1, 50)
    abc(intI) = Len(arrData(intI))
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Manual_Checks").Cells(1, 2 + intI) = arrData(intI)
Next
```

The For loop extracts each block of 50 characters, assigns them to an array of strings and then to the target cell, and then grabs the length from the String array to verify the length.

`intI * 50 + 1` will start the Mid at `{1,51,101,151,201}`.
`2 + intI` will target cell columns `{2,3,4,5,6}`.